# Customize SocialCommentControl in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, comments

I am trying to replicate the functionality provided by the `Social Collaboration > Note Board` but instead of commenting on the current page I want to be able to comment on the current list item being viewed.

The list item in rendered on a web part by grabbing the item id from the query string. For example:

```
http://my-site/Pages/default.aspx?ItemId=6dfb7b80-81AA-4e1d-9ba0-4c8c0819c14e&
```

I tried embedding the

```
sharepointportalcontrols:SocialCommentControl id="CommentControl" runat="server"
```

control into the web part and setting its `Url` (internal property) using reflection. But when commenting the comments still post to the current page.

Is there a way to make the comments post on the current list item instead?

Answer (score 0):

Realized the comment control does a form post back and I wasn't setting the `Url` on postback. Once I moved my databinding code so it happened on postback as well comments started working.

Markup:

```xml
<SharePointPortalControls:SocialCommentControl ID="comments" runat="server" />
```

Backend: (Inside a repeater item data bound)

```cs
SocialCommentControl commentsControl = (SocialCommentControl) e.Item.FindControl("comments");

            if (commentsControl != null)
            {
                commentsControl.SetProperty("AllowNewComment", true);
                commentsControl.SetProperty("DisplayItems", 5);
                commentsControl.SetProperty("Uri", new Uri(itemUrl));
            }
```